# Javascript in Shiny app only loads once

Tags: shiny

### Edit: Generalized question by finding reproducible example

The app below has two `tabPanels`, each with some Javascript within a `sidebarPanel`. I expect the Javascript in Tab 1 to run anytime Tab 1 is activated (i.e., when I initially launch the app and when I navigate back to Tab 1 from Tab 2). Also, I expect the Javascript in Tab 2 to run anytime I navigate to that tab.

Instead, the Javascript for both tabs runs immediately upon launching the app and then never again.

As context, I constructed this example because I ran into this problem while trying to use Javascript to place an Amazon Associates ad in my Shiny app.

### Reproducible example

```
library(shiny)

ui = navbarPage( "",
                  tabPanel( "Tab 1",
                            mainPanel(

                              wellPanel("Blah blah blah"), 
                              width = 6
                            ),

                            sidebarPanel(

                              # only runs once, like the ads
                              HTML('<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Tab 1 is talking"); </script>')

                              # # runs every time
                              #HTML('<b> test </b>')

                              , width=6 )
                  ),

                  tabPanel( "Tab 2",

                            mainPanel(
                              wellPanel("Blah blah blah"), 
                              width = 6

                            ),  # ends mainPanel

                            sidebarPanel(

                              # only runs once, like the ads
                              HTML('<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Tab 2 is talking"); </script>')

                              # # runs every time
                              #HTML('<b> test </b>')

                              , width=6 )

                            )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

app = shinyApp( ui, server )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabs only toggle visibility of content already on the page. So when the app launches, Tab 2 is actually loaded but hidden. If you want tabs to dynamically add and remove scripts, you could use `renderUI` to do this based on the active tab. Or `sendCustomMessage` and `addCustomMessageHandler`.

Here's an example using `renderUI`:

```
library(shiny)

ui = navbarPage("", id = "navbar",
  tabPanel( "Tab 1",
           mainPanel(
             wellPanel("Blah blah blah"), 
             width = 6
           ),

           sidebarPanel(
             uiOutput("tab1"),
             width = 6
           )
  ),

  tabPanel( "Tab 2",
           mainPanel(
             wellPanel("Blah blah blah"), 
             width = 6
           ),

           sidebarPanel(
             uiOutput("tab2"),
             width=6 
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tab1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$navbar == "Tab 1")
    HTML('<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Tab 1 is talking"); </script>')
  })

  output$tab2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$navbar == "Tab 2")
    HTML('<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Tab 2 is talking"); </script>')
  })
}

shinyApp( ui, server )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, although this does solve the reproducible example, it doesn't seem to work for arbitrary Javascript (of the form <script>[define global variables</script> <script src = XXX></script>). The Javascript works when placed directly in the first tab, but fails with renderUI.